# Crafting a higher level scroll

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, crafting

I am a wizard who can cast 2nd level arcane spells. I want to create a scroll of a 3rd level arcane spell. Would this even be possible?

Under the [creating magic item rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#)

> The DC to create a magic item increases by 5 for each prerequisite the caster does not meet. The only exception to this is the requisite item creation feat, which is mandatory. In addition, you cannot create potions, spell-trigger, or spell-completion magic items without meeting its prerequisites.

But nothing specifically says what the prerequisites are. Not [scrolls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Scrolls) further down, not [scribe scrolls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/scribe-scroll-item-creation/) feat, not the page on [magic items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls/) scrolls.

Learning the spell isnt an issue as under the magic rules for [adding new spells to a wizards spellbook](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Adding_Spells_to_a_Wizard8217s_Spellbook) doesnt have any restriction on the level of spell compared to your own casting ability.

Scribe scrolls stated that you are able to craft a scroll of ANY spell you know.

On the crafting magic items page it says that the feat is required as well as one of three skills. It also TALKS about casting the spell but that doesnt have required next to it.

Answer (score 3):

When the [Scribe Scroll](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Scrolls) feat's benefit says, "You can create a scroll of any spell that you know," it's not supplying mechanics. Instead, that sentence serves as the beginning scroll scriber's introduction to scribing scrolls. While that statement is *technically* inaccurate, this reader is willing to forgive that impropriety and say that it's close enough. This reader totally understands if another reader wants to read it differently, though, but if that other reader does that other reader must contend such inaccuracies throughout the game and, perhaps, alter the game to match its hyperbolic mandates (e.g. the even more deceptive benefit of the [Craft Rod](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Adding_Spells_to_a_Wizard8217s_Spellbook) feat: "You can create magic rods").

Anyway, that said, a wizard prepares the spell that's to be triggered to create the scroll. Then the wizard, in the act of creating that scroll, triggers the spell ([see here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Scrolls)). A wizard *can* have in her spellbook a spell that's too high a spell level for her to cast ([see here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Adding_Spells_to_a_Wizard8217s_Spellbook)), but, as the wizard doesn't have spell slots yet suitable for *preparing* that spell, the wizard can't *trigger* that spell during the course of item creation.

If I may be so bold as to make an assumption, I think that the question that may be being asked here is actually this question: ***Where does the game say that between triggering the spell that's to be scribed onto a scroll and actually scribing the scroll that the triggered spell's caster level is the same as the scribed spell's caster level?***

And you'd be right: The game doesn't provide that detail. However, before the skilled reader *can* make hay out of that unmentioned detail, on [Magic Item Creation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/) says that a wizard "can create an item [in this case, a scroll] at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell" ([see here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/)). Be careful here, though, and ask the GM for clarification! This GM has always ruled that this sentence means that a wizard *can't* create a magic item at a *higher* caster level than her own but only up to a caster level *equal* to her own.

(That is, this reader suspects that the sentence's intention is that *A wizard can't create an item at a higher caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell*, making the sentence much more palatable with *both* of the opening clause's modifiers (*can* to *can't*, *lower* to *higher*) flipped. This reader understands if this is a bridge too far for other readers.)

As the question notes, triggering that spell appears *not* to be labeled as a prerequisite for scribing the scroll. However, it wouldn't matter if triggering the spell *were* labeled a prerequisite as skipping triggering the spell by increasing the Spellcraft skill check DC by +5 to create the item, as the question also notes, isn't an option anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## You need to have the spell supplied to craft the scroll.

[Magic Item Creation](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Magic%20Item%20Creation&Category=Magic%20Items) Rules say:

> Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed). The DC to create a magic item increases by +5 for each prerequisite the caster does not meet. The only exception to this is the requisite item creation feat, which is mandatory. *In addition, you cannot create potions, spell-trigger, or **spell-completion** magic items without meeting their spell prerequisites.*

[Using Magic Items](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Using%20Items&Category=Magic%20Items) says:

> Spell Completion: **This is the activation method for scrolls.** A scroll is a spell that is mostly finished. The preparation is done for the caster, so no preparation time is needed beforehand as with normal spellcasting. All that’s left to do is perform the finishing parts of the spellcasting (the final gestures, words, and so on). To use a spell completion item safely, a character must be of high enough level in the right class to cast the spell already. If he can’t already cast the spell, there’s a chance he’ll make a mistake. Activating a spell completion item is a standard action (or the spell’s casting time, whichever is longer) and provokes attacks of opportunity exactly as casting a spell does.

Since scrolls are a Spell-Completion magic item, you are required to meet the spell prerequisites for crafting them.

If we look at the rules for [creating scrolls](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Creating%20Scrolls&Category=Magic%20Item%20Creation), we see:

> **The creator must have prepared the spell to be scribed** (or must know the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any material component or focus the spell requires. A material component is consumed when she begins writing, but a focus is not. (A focus used in scribing a scroll can be reused.) The act of writing triggers the prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting until the character has rested and regained spells. (That is, that spell slot is expended from the caster’s currently prepared spells, just as if it had been cast.)

As a wizard you must have the spell prepared in order to craft a scroll of the spell. Since you are not able to do so, you cannot craft a scroll of it on your own. Therefore, in order to craft a scroll the spell must be supplied during the creation of it.

Comment: I find it interesting that our sources are a little different, but the one you use is the more official one simply because of the partnership between them and Piazo.